# (Flask API), make firebase uploaded images have unique names

Tags: python, firebase, flask, firebase-storage, flash-message

I'm building an API that uploads images to Firebase storage, everything works as expected in that regard, the problem is that the syntax makes me specify the file name in each upload, and in production mode the API will receive upload requests from multiple devices, so I need to make to code so it checks for an available id, set it for the "blob()" object, and then do a normal upload, but I have no idea how to do that. or a random name I don't care as long as it doesn't overwrite another picture

Here is my current code:

```
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, auth, storage, firestore
import os
import io


cred = credentials.Certificate('service_account_key.json')
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {'storageBucket': 'MY-DATABASE-NAME.appspot.com'})

bucket = storage.bucket()
blob = bucket.blob("images/newimage.png") #here is where im guessing i #should put the next available name

# "apple.png" is a sample image #for testing in my directory
with open("apple.png", "rb") as f:
    blob.upload_from_file(f)
```

Comment: That is exactly what UUIDs are made for. See the `uuid` module.

Comment: I just google it up, I think that would fix it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As "Klaus D."'s comment said the solution was to implement the "uuid" module

```
import uuid

.....
.....
blob = bucket.blob("images/" + str(uuid.uuid4()))
```